# А возможно ли выбрать несколько полей, только в случайном порядке?

Tags: php, mysql

напр.

```
SELECT RANDOM(field_A,field_B,field_C,field_D) FROM `table`;
```

Но это я так, образно, на самом деле мне просто нужно чтобы поля были в *случайном порядке* (**не путать со случайно выбранными записями**).

Comment: мешай их уже средствами пхп

Comment: да это легко, я просто думал сразу как-то можно, чтобы уже пхп ни дергать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то нет такой возможности средствами mysql.

Comment: очень даже может быть.

Comment: @Maris, если найдете, то обязательно отпишите. Пригодится всем :)

Comment: Не ошибаетесь - нет. Да и вообще, глупо надеяться на то, что mysql выдаст столбцы в неком конкретном порядке.

Comment: да, лучше как-то сразу их рендомно определить и запрос составить.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше это сделать так.

1. Получить в массив список полей у таблицы (кеш)
2. Перемешать массив
3. через `implode` указать список полей

Comment: да это я и сам знаю, просто как-то... Если у меня напр. 10 таких запросов и к каждому такое приделать, то еще ладно, а вот если 30 и более уже как-то не радует, но это я так, как всегда `образно`.

Comment: Держите все в кеше, чтоб не обращаться каждый раз. Или же вы можете описать массив в вашей модели. По любому вам нужны будут эти поля которые нужно перемешивать.